# Getting driver status returns always null. Why?

Tags: c#, wmi

I using WMI in order to get all drivers in system:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPSignedDriver");

foreach (ManagementObject WmiObject in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "ClassGuid", WmiObject["ClassGuid"]);// String
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "DeviceClass", WmiObject["DeviceClass"]);// String
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "DeviceID", WmiObject["DeviceID"]);// String
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "DeviceName", WmiObject["DeviceName"]);// String
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "Manufacturer", WmiObject["Manufacturer"]);// String
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "Name", WmiObject["Name"]);// String
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-35} {1,-40}", "Status", WmiObject["Status"]);// String
}
```

For some reason, 'Status' is always null. I running as Administrator on Windows 10.

Any ideas what I doing wrong?

Comment: are you running the VS or the .exe file as an administrator ?

Comment: I just queried Win32_PnpSignedDriver on my Windows 10 system with PowerShell. Same result: Status is always null. No difference when run as admin.

Comment: @Babekoof - tried both, same result

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is wrong. Why do you want to go to `Win32_PnPSignedDriver` ?
You can achieve more if you check out the `Win32_SystemDriver`, which will return you the state, status and started as you wish. Use the following class example, to get the information you need:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows;

namespace Agent.cls
{
    public class Hw
    {
        public int DeviceId;
        public bool AcceptPause;
        public bool AcceptStop;
        public string Caption;
        public string CreationClassName;
        public string Description;
        public bool DeskTopInteract;
        public string DisplayName;
        public string ErrorControl;
        public int ExitCode;
        public DateTime InstallDate;
        public string Name;
        public string PathName;
        public int ServiceSpecificExitCode;
        public string ServiceType;
        public bool started;
        public string StartMode;
        public string StartName;
        public string State;
        public string Status;
        public string SystemCreationClassName;
        public string SystemName;
        public int TagId;

        public static ObservableCollection<Hw> GetDevices()
        {
            var deviceList = new ObservableCollection<Hw>();
            try
            {
                var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_SystemDriver");
                var seracher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

                var counter = 0;
                foreach (var wmiObject in seracher.Get())
                {
                    var newDevice = new Hw
                    {
                        DeviceId = counter,
                        AcceptPause = Convert.ToBoolean(wmiObject["AcceptPause"]),
                        AcceptStop = Convert.ToBoolean(wmiObject["AcceptStop"]),
                        Caption = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["Caption"]),
                        CreationClassName = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["CreationClassName"]),
                        Description = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["Description"]),
                        DeskTopInteract = Convert.ToBoolean(wmiObject["DeskTopInteract"]),
                        DisplayName = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["DisplayName"]),
                        ErrorControl = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["ErrorControl"]),
                        ExitCode = Convert.ToInt16(wmiObject["ExitCode"]),
                        InstallDate = Convert.ToDateTime(wmiObject["InstallDate"]),
                        Name = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["Name"]),
                        PathName = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["PathName"]),
                        ServiceSpecificExitCode = Convert.ToInt16(wmiObject["ServiceSpecificExitCode"]),
                        ServiceType = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["ServiceType"]),
                        started = Convert.ToBoolean(wmiObject["Started"]),
                        StartMode = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["StartMode"]),
                        StartName = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["StartName"]),
                        State = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["State"]),
                        Status = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["Status"]),
                        SystemCreationClassName = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["SystemCreationClassName"]),
                        SystemName = Convert.ToString(wmiObject["SystemName"]),
                        TagId = Convert.ToInt16(wmiObject["TagId"])
                    };
                    deviceList.Add(newDevice);
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error in device list \n\n" + e);
            }
            return deviceList;
        }
    }
}
```

btw, with this object, you can start,stop,pause drivers